# Example of a finite group

Tags: group-theory

I need an example of a finite group $G$ such that

1) the number of Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is $1$ for all $p\neq 2$

2) the number of Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ is $3$.

Comment: What are their motivations with these questions?

Comment: What do you need the group for? What are your thoughts on how one might construct one?

Comment: Try the smallest possible example!!

Comment: To follow up on @SteveD's comment, (2) tells you that the group is non-abelian. Think of the non-abelian (small) group(s) you know.

Answer (score 1):

Hints (in the correct order): any finite abelian group, non-abelian group of order $\,6\,$ ...

Comment: I take OP wants a single group that satisfies both conditions.

Comment: Ok, then only the second hinted one (the smallest non-abelian group)